# What does this mean, " Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-("?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I found it in my xampp/htdocs/index.php. How can it be resolved?

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $uri = 'https://';
} else {
    $uri = 'http://';
}
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

Note: My XAMMP installation can run my local WordPress install.

Comment: If you google on that string: _"Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-("_, there are may many posts about it. You should start by going through them.

Comment: I did, none were really helpful. The posts on Google discuss php not working. Php is running on my machine despite the string.

Comment: Could you please check error log or share it in question

Comment: There are many logs. I'm not sure where to find what is needed.

Comment: it appear on a webpage or u just find it while looking on the script page ? Because what i know is this script is load when u launch apache (and u havent change the directory root) and it's testing if the uri is working, if it's, you get redirected to the dashboard, if not u get the message.

Comment: It appeared in the index.php of the htdocs folder. I deleted the line and it didn't show anymore. I have always been redirected to the admin dashboard.

Comment: try to look into the apache error log, there may be multiple entries, either you may delete them all, or just refresh the page and see if any new entry inserted in the log file. Also, I would suggest removing all code, and print phpinfo(),check what it is returning.

Answer (score 0):

Try running localhost/filename.php
Instead of running file with given address like c:/xampp/htdocs/filename.php
Hope it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I have to add my 2 cents if anyone stumbles upon this error.
My problem was that the `PHP` `apache` module wasn't loaded properly i.e. the path to the module wasn't properly set.

In `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` file I changed the path to look at the right place

```
LoadModule php_module "/xampp/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
```